# Probability that $(x \vee y \vee z)$ is satisfied

Tags: probability

Suppose you have the clause $(x \vee y \vee z)$ with $x,y,z$ set to a random true/false value. What is the probability that this clause is satisifed?

Suppose you have $m$ clauses in 3 conjunctive normal form (of the form in the previous problem), where each clause has exactly 3 literals on different variables (so $y$ and $\neg y$ don't appear in the same clause). If the variables are randomly set to True and False, what is the expected number of satisfied clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(x\lor y\lor z)=1-P(\bar x\land\bar y\land\bar z)=1-P(\bar x)P(\bar y)P(\bar z)=\frac78$$

Comment: So would the second just be $\frac{m*7}{8}$?

Comment: A priori no. But the formulation of this part of your question is too imprecise to know for sure.

Comment: Why is it too imprecise?

Comment: To begin with, how many literals to build the m clauses?

Comment: Three. The $m$ clauses are in "3 conjunctive normal form" which means they take the form $(x \vee y \vee z)$, and each clause has exactly 3 literals on different variables.

Comment: You did not answer my question. How many literals to build the $m$ clauses? Just $3$? Or $3m$? Or some number inbetween?